# Is there a way to detect onDestroy in Recyclerview Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Every item of my Recyclerview has a button that show a custom dialog. The code for showing dialog is inside of my adapter.

My problem is sometimes I get the `Window Manager : android view window leaked` cause of not closing the dialog before closing the activity.

So, I would like to know if there is a way to detect destroying the adapter so I can close the dialog.

I tried to `override onDestroy` but it seems like the function is not for adapter.

Comment: Use DialogFragment and never face leaked windows again.